# Activerecord Return existing record if it exists on create or save of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

### Problem

I would like to return an existing record, if one exists, whenever save(!) or create(!) are called on a model using validation in the model itself, *WITHOUT* using first_or_create from an external controller or associated model. If no record exists, it should create/save a new record and return it.

### Detail

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 4 project where I have a very simple model which stores Sha1 hashes.  Other than the default columns, it has a single column called "hexdigest" which is a unique index.  Sha1 has a has_many relationship to several other models, each of which may contain zero or more records related to a single Sha.  The problem I have is that I would like to always return an existing record, if one exists, anytime a `Sha1#save` or `Sha1.create` are called by any other model/controller/etc.  I have been trying to do this in the model itself, but have not been able to find a good solution to this problem as yet.

Below is a simple representation of the model (the actual model has very little additional complexity):

```
class Sha1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :git_repos

  validates :hexdigest,
             presence: true,
             length: { is: 40 },
             format: { with: /\A[a-f0-9]+\z/ }
end
```

Presently, I am managing the uniqueness of the Sha1 record for associated models using a Concern:

```
module BelongsToSha
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :sha1
    before_validation :get_sha1
    validates :sha1, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sha1
  end

  def get_sha1
    if !sha1.nil? && sha1.new_record?
      self.sha1 = Sha1.find_or_create_by(hexdigest: self.sha1.hexdigest)
    end
  end
end
```

Which has the simple effect of ensuring the associated Sha1 for a new record is resolved to an existing sha1 on save, if one exists.

However, if I try to create/save a Sha1 manually from somewhere else (in a test, controller, or other code), it fails because the first_or_create is not resolved directly on the model:

```
Sha1.create(hexdigest: '0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33')
Sha1.create(hexdigest: '0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33') # results in a record not unique error
```

I managed to resolve the issue on `create` by overriding create on the Sha1 model:

```
def self.create(attributes, &block)
  first || super
end

def self.create!(attributes, &block)
  first || super
end
```

But, the problem still occurs on save, as ActiveRecord goes down a different execution path on `create` and `save`.  So the following still fails with an exception:

```
Sha1.new(hexdigest: '0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33').save
Sha1.new(hexdigest: '0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33').save # results in a record not unique error
```

It already feels like a hack to override create, but I have not found a better way to do this. It seems now that I would also need to override `save` and `save!`, but have not had success with this as yet.  It would be preferrable to use callbacks, but callbacks only allow escaping create/save by returning false or raising an exception, which would cause the entire transaction to be rolled back when the Sha1 is being auto-saved/created through an association.

I've made several attempts at this and the BelongsToSha concern has been the best solution as yet, but does not work in all situations as described above.  I do not want to raise errors or `valid? #=> false` when a duplicate record is attempted to be saved or created; rather, I want to simply return the existing one in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately neither of the above answers actually resolved my original problem.  After a good amount of trial and error, I found that the ActiveSupport::Concern approach mentioned in my original post seems to be the closest/best solution I could achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the following: `find_or_create_by`

```
Sha1.find_or_create_by(hexdigest: '0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33')
```

It will find OR create your Sha1 record based on hexidigest AND return the instance.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Answer (score 0):

First of all, hopefully you have a SQL constraint on your hexdigest column. Ruby callbacks cannot validate uniqueness atomically. Let me repeat this. Ruby callback **cannot** validate uniqueness atomically.

Now, onto your problem, what I would do is, create a new save method on your sha1 model.

```
def save_unique!
  while
    self.hexdigest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(123123)) if self.hexdigest.nil?
    self.save!
    break
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
end
```

This recursively guarantees uniqueness